# Apple app store support ios app with dylib

Tags: ios, frameworks, app-store, dylib, xcframework

I am trying to make an ios app with a dylib as framework instead of the standard .framework or .xcframework structure.

Does the app store review work with such a shared library structure.

I see from here that it might not be supported.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2435/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40017543-CH1-TROUBLESHOOTING-BUNDLE_ERRORS

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/125796

Has anyone tried an app with a dylib inside ? Or it has to be packaged as framework instead ?

Answer (score 0):

From your first link:

> Dynamic libraries outside of a framework bundle, which typically have
> the file extension .dylib, are not supported on iOS, watchOS, or tvOS,
> except for the system Swift libraries provided by Xcode.

That seems unambiguous in saying that you can't include a dynamic library outside a framework.

Comment: I asked to check if some one has tried it, there are mixed answers overs the internet. Thats why.